# Parent / Child relationships in interfaces

Tags: c#

If I were to have interfaces like so:

```
public interface IAlbum
{
    string Title { get; set; }
}

public interface ITrack
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    float Duration { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the best way to add a list of tracks to the IAlbum interface?  What if I wanted the individual tracks to be properties and not have an exposed array of tracks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of tracks could be either:

```
IList<ITrack> Tracks {get;}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<ITrack> Tracks {get;}
```

If you want the concrete type to expose a more concrete API, you could implement the above via explicit implementation.

You could in theory make:

```
interface IAlbum : IEnumerable<ITrack> {...}
```

but I don't think that is a good idea.

Re exposing tracks as properties; if I understand correctly, you could do this "kind of" at runtime by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` on the concrete album type. But it is non-trivial and a bit messy - and it won't help hugely unless you are using data-binding.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx). Specifically:

```
    ITrack this[int trackIndex]
    {
        get;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also provide an indexer that works with a track title.  This is [sort of] between properties for the tracks and having a collection.

```
ITrack this[string trackName]
{
    get { return getTraxckUsingName(trackName); }
}
```